# DFT product of sinusoids

Tags: dft

(From Shaums DSP outline, 2nd edition, page 248, problem 6.21)

Book says, evaluate the Sum:

$$
S = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} \Bigg( x_1[n] \ x^{*}_2[n] \Bigg)
$$

when:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1[n] = \cos\left( \frac{2\pi n k_1}{N} \right) \\
\\
x_2[n] = \cos\left( \frac{2\pi n k_2}{N} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

using Property:

$$
\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} \Bigg( x_1[n]\  x^{*}_2[n] \Bigg) = \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}  \Bigg(  X_1[k]\ X_2^{*}[k]\Bigg)
$$

---

I start by converting cosines into complex exponentials:

$$
x_1[n] = \cos\left( \frac{2\pi n k_1}{N} \right) 
$$

$$
x_1[n] =  0.5e^{j2\pi n k_1 / N}  + 0.5e^{-j 2\pi n k_1 / N}
$$

Applying Definition of DFT to find:
$$
X_1[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \Bigg( 0.5e^{j2\pi n k_1 / N}  + 0.5e^{-j 2\pi n k_1 / N} \Bigg) e^{-j2\pi nk/N}
$$

$$
X_1[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \Bigg( 0.5e^{-j(2\pi n/N)(k- k_1)}  + 0.5e^{-j(2\pi n/N)(k+ k_1)} \Bigg)
$$

From this I determine that sum over one period of a complex exponential is zero, except when k is selected to cancel out exponential function input to zero, such as when $k=k_1$ and $k=-k_1$.  Thus:

$$
X_1[k] = \begin{cases}
\frac{N}{2}&(k=k_1)\ or\ (k=-k_1) \\
0 & else
\end{cases}
$$

By similar means:
$$
X_2[k] = \begin{cases}
\frac{N}{2}&(k=k_2)\ or\ (k=-k_2) \\
0 & else
\end{cases}
$$

Here's where I get lost:

Books says, therefore:

$$
\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x_{1}[n] x^{*}_{2}[n] = \frac{1}{N}\Bigg[ \frac{N^2}{4} + \frac{N^2}{4} \Bigg] = \frac{N}{2}
$$

Where does: 
$$
 \frac{N^2}{4} + \frac{N^2}{4}
 $$
come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have quite done it, but lets indicate.

When the frequencies of both sinusoidal signals $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ are the same; i.e., $k_1 = k_2 = m$, then the **impulses** in the corresponding N-point DFT sequences $X_1[k]$ and $X_2[k]$ will occur at the same index $k=m$ and $k=-m$ (or $N-m$) with a weight of $N/2$.

Hence multiplication of $X_1[k]$ with $X_2[k]$  will be $N/2 * N/2 + N/2 * N/2 = N^2/2$, as there are two impulses in the DFT of a cosine signal...

Finally dividing by $N$ yields the result as $N/2$ when the frequencies are the same and $0$ when not.

Comment: would it be: $(1/N)\sum^{N-1}_{k=0}X_{1}[k]X^{*}_{2}[k] = (1/N)(X_{1}[k_1{]}X^{*}_{2}[k_{1}] + X_1[k_{2}]X^{*}_{2}[k_{2}])$

Comment: $X_1[k_1] = N/2$, and $X_2[k_2] = N/2$, when I plug in... I get a mysterious $X_{1}^{*}[k_2]$ and $X_{2}^{*}[k_1]$ that has a value that is not nice and clean..

Comment: actually, $X^*_1[k_2]$ should equal zero for $k_2$?  no idea.. its a mystery

Comment: assuming $k_1 \ne k_2$ … or maybe its required that $k_1 = k_2$

Comment: ahh...ok...that's the answer...  the product is zero unless $k_1 = k_2$... some type of frequency correlation problem...

Comment: yes the product is zero unless k1 = k2, as they are **orthgonal** signals...